# Evince garbles pdflatex output on some zoom levels

Tags: latex, evince

I use pdflatex to generate PDFs but one of them produces garbled text in evince on certain zoom levels, while at others it looks perfectly normal. Is this a problem with the .tex file or with Evince and how can I fix it?

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of the garbled PDF output]

### Versions

pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20

Evince Version 3.32.0

Arch Linux 5.2.14-arch2-1-ARCH

GNOME Shell 3.32.2

### Files

The .tex file (MWE):

```
\documentclass[sw]{iosart2x}

\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a fringilla elit. Morbi id nibh odio. Cras ac quam fermentum, rhoncus urna non, lacinia mi. Nunc tincidunt dictum mauris non congue. Cras faucibus accumsan arcu, id sollicitudin lectus euismod sit amet. Aenean eu mauris vitae nisi molestie bibendum. Duis leo orci, pulvinar a consequat a, laoreet sit amet dolor. Mauris libero diam, finibus id commodo vel, lobortis sed dolor. Morbi cursus dui sit amet auctor tincidunt. Quisque aliquam ipsum sed iaculis bibendum. Vivamus a blandit libero, et bibendum lorem.

 Cras scelerisque ornare libero id posuere. Aenean vestibulum iaculis mauris, sed faucibus diam sodales eu. Proin sed efficitur augue, sit amet volutpat mi. Vivamus at odio sit amet arcu molestie feugiat. Ut blandit volutpat facilisis. Donec iaculis arcu id imperdiet pretium. Suspendisse sodales tristique metus ac venenatis. Aenean et mattis purus. Sed quis sapien velit.

 Fusce nulla velit, aliquam sit amet elit ac, varius egestas tellus. Morbi vestibulum urna a diam consequat, nec rutrum lectus placerat. Vivamus venenatis id enim ac finibus. Maecenas consequat tempor arcu. Nam aliquet leo quis feugiat pellentesque. Vivamus nec lobortis quam, eget tempus ipsum. Donec nisl lorem, consectetur sed ullamcorper a, elementum ac lacus. Vestibulum maximus mollis est sed sodales. Nulla ante ante, placerat sit amet diam blandit, pretium dapibus diam. Praesent maximus feugiat turpis non varius. Vivamus malesuada risus ut leo volutpat consectetur. Sed vel ante pulvinar dui maximus blandit eget sit amet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla metus ex, dapibus sed urna at, sodales molestie justo.                                                                                      

 Sed sed scelerisque odio. Quisque sed venenatis augue. Morbi nec iaculis nibh. Nulla nec vehicula felis, sit amet vestibulum massa. Pellentesque sollicitudin enim sit amet lacinia eleifend. Proin quis augue eros. Cras sagittis orci a pellentesque dictum. Donec dapibus mollis mi et maximus. Vivamus pulvinar elit volutpat, consectetur arcu quis, euismod diam. Sed nec eros libero. Maecenas fermentum, purus vitae suscipit dignissim, libero nisi blandit lectus, nec pellentesque velit odio eu velit. Vestibulum feugiat dui turpis, a blandit diam molestie eget. Morbi aliquam nunc vel lectus rhoncus cursus. Curabitur vel ex ultricies, placerat augue sit amet, lacinia ipsum. Vivamus ultricies ut augue vitae faucibus. Cras euismod pretium metus ac venenatis.

 Proin placerat id justo at iaculis. Donec mollis dignissim sem ac facilisis. Praesent dictum convallis velit eget ultrices. Aliquam volutpat odio ultricies neque pretium gravida. Pellentesque ex lectus, imperdiet non lacinia quis, auctor sit amet libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed ex mi, faucibus eget vehicula vitae, porta nec arcu. Fusce eget odio lacus. Vivamus laoreet fringilla augue sit amet commodo. Nullam maximus nec est ac laoreet. Donec quam diam, fringilla vitae pretium a, tempor ac magna.
\end{document}
```

I also attached [the log file](https://pastebin.com/raw/HrQn2qfU) but now I don't see the error anymore in the MWE. So I also [attached the original PDF](https://github.com/IMISE/snik-paper-swj/raw/evince-error/paper.pdf), where I still get the error.

Comment: To get the best possible answer you should share both `.tex` file and output PDF.

Comment: Can you share the .log file of the MWE? There might be a problem with embedding the fonts. And as  Arkadiusz Drabczyk said, it would be helpful to have the pdf for testing

Comment: do you get the same problem in `qpdfview` or `okular`?   also, install the `poppler-utils` package, it contains many useful pdf utilities - e.g. `pdffonts` can list which fonts are used by and/or embedded in the PDF file.

Comment: BTW, `pdffonts paper.pdf` says that one of the embedded fonts in your PDF is a Type 3 font called `[none]` (which may be a default name replacing an empty string).  This is just a guess but it may be what is confusing evince.